# CakePHP security won't unlock date fields

Tags: cakephp-2.0

CakePHP security allows you to "unlock" certain form fields that you know can't be relied upon. For example, when I dynamically hide all "Spouse" input fields because my user isn't married, I have to unlock those fields or else the security component will black-hole the request.

```
// submitting form works when these lines are in the view, but hidden by JS
echo $this->Form->input('Spouse.0.first_name'));
$this->Form->unlockField('Spouse.0.first_name');
```

But when an input is a date, CakePHP automagically creates 3 dropdowns whose names are based on my field: month, day, and year, and "unlocking" them doesn't work

```
// submitting form fails when these lines are in the view but hidden by JS
echo $this->Form->input('Spouse.0.date_of_birth');
$this->Form->unlockField('Spouse.0.date_of_birth');
```

So how do I unlock date fields?